# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting this error when I am trying to run my application using eclipse.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties
```

and this is my configuration inside spring-servlet.xml

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

and my project folder structure is

```
src
 --main
   -- java
application.properties

Webcontent
--WEB-INF
  --jsp
  --lib
```

I build this project using POM.xml

war file is created inside target folder

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: make a folder under your WEB-INF and call it classes. copy your properties file in there and check it again !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like the file is anywhere that would be added to the WAR. Put it under `src/main/resources`, which is the conventional Maven location for non-source code resources.